# JS - WebAuthn - How to disable or detect screen lock (PIN Code) option

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, platform, webauthn

I'm looking a solution to authenticate by finger print without "screen lock" option

I tried to change authenticator attachment to "platform",
And add some extensions with uvi, uvm options got nothing :\
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PublicKeyCredentialCreationOptions/extensions

```
authenticatorSelection: {
    authenticatorAttachment: "platform"
},
```

```
extensions : {
    uvi: true,
    uvm: true
},
```

Disable PIN code option or detect finger screen authentication

Answer (score 0):

Uvm will work at Chrome 77 (Todat it's Dev version):